# Visual Studio Test Explorer Can't find source

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a Dll which contains lots of tests, like 1200 of them.  The tests run fine and can be debugged. However I can't click on the test to go to the source this is supper annoying.

I went about and did some due diligence on fixing the issue. The first thing I did was run symchk.  This is where it got really confusing.  The dll in question fails symchk if I just ran `symchk my.dll` however if i ran `symchk /s TheCurrentFolder` it said it passed. My understanding is that if the pdb is in the same folder it should be found automatically.

I went and dumped the headers of the dll and found that the debug info was in the dll and pointed to the correct file. Lastly I added the pdb to the symbol cache ran symchk and it failed again stating that a file which does exist does not.

So the Question is has anyone ran into this before and is there something I can do about it.  Obviously visual studio is able to load the pdb but the test engine can't.

Comment: I have same issue in VS2013. Tests are recognized and executed fine, but "Open Test" (F12) does not work. It says Cannot open file. Although the files are part of solution and can be opened manually just fine.

Comment: I'm running into this problem for 1 week (VS2019). If something fails the trace is shown properly, and takes you to the correct file / line, though.